# Laravel 4, Ubuntu, SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ubuntu-12.04, laravel-4, php-5.3, freetds

I'm using default PHP 5.3.10 in my ubuntu box. and install php5-sysbase.

I tested with this code and success connected to my SQL Server

```
<?php
        $link = mssql_connect('125.0.0.1', 'sa', '12345');
        if(!$link) {
                echo'Could not connect';
                die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_error());
        }
        echo'Successful connection';
        mssql_close($link);
```

Now I'm following the quickstart tutorial until arrive at database things in http://laravel.com/docs/quick#creating-a-migration

I use default db driver `sqlsrv`, with this config:

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => '125.0.0.1',
            'database' => 'laravel',
            'username' => 'sa',
            'password' => '12345',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
```

When I execute `php artisan migrate`, I got an error

```
[Exception]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 102 General SQL Server error: Check message
  s from the SQL Server [102] (severity 15) [(null)] (SQL: create table "migr
  ations" ("migration" nvarchar(255) not null, "batch" int not null)) (Bindin
  gs: array (
  ))
```

What could be the problem? Thanks for any helps

**EDIT01:**

here's sql message:

```
message_id  language_id severity    is_event_logged text
102 1033    15  0   Incorrect syntax near '%.*ls'.
```

here's my migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

Comment: If I create the database manually, the simple query works though

Comment: did you check your sql server logs manually? The message says "check messages from the SQL Server"

Comment: can you please post your migration file(s)?

Comment: i've edited my post with migration file content, and sql log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/SqlServerGrammar.php
```

Change this:

```
protected $wrapper = '"%s"';
```

To this:

```
protected $wrapper = '[%s]';
```

Comment: Hey sorry to rehash this, but this is exactly what I needed! Thanks. Question though, would this affect any of the other db connections?